# Reimplementing data structures in the real world

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

The topic of algorithms class today was reimplementing data structures, specifically ArrayList in Java.  The fact that you can customize a structure for in various ways definitely got me interested, particularly with variations of add() & iterator.remove() methods.

But is reimplementing and customizing a data structure something that is of more interest to the academics vs the real-world programmers?  Has anyone reimplemented their own version of a data structure in a commercial application/program, and why did you pick that route over your particular language's implementation?

Answer (score 5):

Knowing how data structures are implemented and can be implemented is definitely of interest to everyone, not just academics. While you will most likely not reimplement a datastructure if the language already provides an implementation with suitable functions and performance characteristics, it is very possible that you will have to create your own data structure by composing other data structures... or you may need to implement a data structure with slightly different behavior than a well-known data structure. In that case, you certainly will need to know how the original data structure is implemented. Alternatively, you may end up needing a data structure that does not exist or which provides similar behavior to an existing data structure, but the way in which it is used requires that it be optimized for a different set of functions. Again, such a situation would require you to know how to implement (and alter) the data structure, so yes it is of interest.

**Edit**
I am **not advocating that you reimplement existing datastructures**! Don't do that. What I'm saying  is that the knowledge does have practical application. For example, you may need to create a bidirectional map data structure (which you can implement by composing two unidirectional map data structures), or you may need to create a stack that keeps track of a variety of statistics (such as min, max, mean) by using an existing stack data structure with an element type that contains the value as well as these various statistics. These are some trivial examples of things that you might need to implement in the real world.

Comment: like combining the random access of ArrayList along with add() and iterator.remove() of LinkedList  to get a more efficient solution to a traveling salesman?

Comment: for example... but pls do not forget, that knowing how to create a really good implementation is not as easy as it looks like. You might want to take many things in mind - performance, interface complexity bounds, concurrency and others.
It is a good exercise, but most of the times, when the situation allows it, avoid reimplementing languages standard library, most of the times, you might get it just wrong.
If you are looking for examples in Java, Google Collections have some specific implementations of their own, check them out:)

Answer (score 3):

I have re-implemented some of a language's built-in data structures, functions, and classes on a number of occasions.  As an embedded developer, the main reason I would do that is for speed or efficiency.  The standard libraries and types were designed to be useful in a variety of situations, but there are many instances where I can create a more specialized version that is custom-tailored to take advantage of the features and limitations of my current platform.  If the language doesn't provide a way to open up and modify existing classes (like you can in Ruby, for instance), then re-implementing the class/function/structure can be the only way to go.

For example, one system I worked on used a MIPS CPU that was speedy when working with 32-bit numbers but slower when working with smaller ones.  I re-wrote several data structures and functions to use 32-bit integers instead of 16-bit integers, and also specified that the fields be aligned to 32-bit boundaries.  The result was a noticable speed boost in a section of code that was bottlenecking other parts of the software.

That being said, it was not a trivial process.  I ended up having to modify every function that used that structure and I ended up having to re-write several standard library functions as well.  In this particular instance, the benefits outweighed the work.  In the general case, however, it's usually not worth the trouble.  There's a big potential for hard-to-debug problems, and it's almost always more work than it looks like.  Unless you have specific requirements or restrictions that the existing structures/classes don't meet, I would recommend against re-implementing them.

As Michael mentions, it is indeed useful to know *how* to re-implement structures even if you never do so.  You may find a problem in the future that can be solved by applying the principles and techniques used in existing data structures.